# Nested transparency in OpenSCAD output

Tags: transparency, openscad

Transparency in OpenSCAD output can be achieved by prepending `%` to elements, but this doesn't allow to put a transparent element in a surrounding element with a higher degree (e.g. expressed in percentage) of transparency and make it possible to see an (opaque) element in a transparent element inside a transparent element. How to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the a-value of `color([r,g,b,a])` can be used to control transparency, e.g.:

```
color([0.5,0.5,0,0.8]) cube(size=[10,10,10], center=true);
%cube(size=[20,20,20], center=true);
```

[image: combination of background-modifier and color()]

or with different colors:

```
color([0.5,0.5,0,0.8]) cube(size=[10,10,10], center=true);
color([0,0.5,0.5,0.3]) cube(size=[20,20,20], center=true);
```

[image: nested transparency]

Comment: Note that the order of declaration of geometries matters.